# Javascript fetch exception causes dead stop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch, fetch-api

I have the following code:

```
        function makeid(length) {
            var result = '';
            var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
            var charactersLength = characters.length;
            for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
                result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 
            charactersLength));
            };
            return result;
        };

        var instance = "{{ user }}" + makeid(16);
        var checksum = "First Request Not recieved";
        console.log(instance);
        function downloadPlay(){
            console.log("\ndownloadPlay - Begin\n")
            try{
                fetch("/file?instance=" + instance + "&checksum=" + checksum)
                .then(function(resp) {
                    resp.headers.forEach(
                        function(val, key) {
                            // console.log("key, val: " + key + ", " + val); 
                            if(key == "checksum"){
                                console.log("checksum: " + val); 
                                checksum = val;
                            };
                        }
                    );
                }
            )
            .then(file => {
                var audio = new Audio("/file?instance=" + instance + "&checksum=" + checksum);
                console.log("Done");
                audio.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
                    delete audio;
                    downloadPlay();
                });
                audio.play();
                }
            )
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Something went wrong, Retrying: " + error);
            }
            console.log("downloadPlay - Complete\n")
        };
        downloadPlay();
```

This works perfectly when the promise succeeds. However when it fails(such as when the client device switches networks, i.e. wifi to data or just different access points on the same wifi network) it stops dead and never resumes no matter how many while loops, extra recursion points or try and catch statements I use. The best I could do so far is get it to play ever increasing numbers of the audio mostly in sync with each other and I just dont understand why. It seems I have a general lack of understanding of how this promise thing actually functions, but no matter how many tutorials I read/watch my lack of understanding seems to remain unchanged.

Heres the code that somewhat worked if that helps:

```
        function makeid(length) {
            var result = '';
            var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
            var charactersLength = characters.length;
            for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
                result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 
            charactersLength));
            };
            return result;
        };

        var instance = "{{ user }}" + makeid(16);
        var checksum = "First Request Not recieved";
        console.log(instance);
        function downloadPlay(){
            console.log("\ndownloadPlay - Begin\n")
            try{
                console.log('fetching')
                fetch("/file?instance=" + instance + "&checksum=" + checksum)
                .then(function(resp) {
                    resp.headers.forEach(
                        function(val, key) {
                            // console.log("key, val: " + key + ", " + val); 
                            if(key == "checksum"){
                                console.log("checksum: " + val); 
                                checksum = val;
                            };
                        }
                    );
                }
            ).catch(function(error) {
                console.log('request failed', error)
                console.log('retrying')
                downloadPlay();
                return;
            })
            .then(file => {
                var audio = new Audio("/file?instance=" + instance + "&checksum=" + checksum);
                console.log("Done");
                audio.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
                    delete audio;
                    downloadPlay();
                });
                audio.play();
                }
            )
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Something went wrong, Retrying: " + error);
            }
            console.log("downloadPlay - Complete\n")
        };
        downloadPlay();
```

Any solution or very simple explanation on what im doing wrong would be much appreciated
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you have code that "somewhat works", then why not use it? In the first snippet I see you output "retrying", but don't actually retry. In the second snippet you have one catch callback that retries, and another that doesn't.

Comment: @trincot. I dont use it because as said in my question, it only somewhat works, in this case meaning. It creates ear rape and also continuously 'increases the volume'.
Thanks for pointing out the retrying but doesn't bit, I gave up calling the function again on failure at that point because I had figured out that it just stops dead. It was an artifact of copy pasting the other part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

Just remove the comment and use your original fetching function

You can't use try catch with promises unless you use async await

```js
const fakeChecking = Promise.resolve({headers: {checksum: 'aaaa'}})
const errorChecking = Promise.reject('error')

function downloadPlay(fetching) {
  console.log("\ndownloadPlay - Begin\n")

  console.log('fetching')
  fetching
    .then((resp) =>  resp.headers.checksum)
    .then(checksum  => {
      /*var audio = new Audio("/file?instance=" + instance + "&checksum=" + checksum);
      console.log("Done");
      /*audio.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
        delete audio;
        downloadPlay();
        console.log("downloadPlay - Complete\n")
      });
      audio.play();*/
      console.log("downloadPlay - Complete\n")
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('request failed', error)
      console.log('retrying')
      downloadPlay(fakeChecking);
    })
   
};

downloadPlay(errorChecking);
```